# ARfoundation- extreme overheating

Tags: performance, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, ar-foundation

My phone gets extra hot when simply testing Unity's sample AR scene, which is an empty scene.
It happens when the ar camera is on. (I even limited the frame rate)
Is there anything to do about that? How do other AR apps don't get so hot? Is it only because of Unity? AR foundation?

Comment: Unity is spectacular inefficient in its default settings, and even ofter massive amounts of optimisation. For any given project, it's never entirely sure what configuration changes will lead to it finally taking it a bit easier on the CPU and GPU... just a trial and error quagmire until you hit upon a formula of configurations and optimisations that gets it somewhat manageable. Worst of all, Unity does no significant internal testing and cannot provide much (or any) insight into best practices for optimisation of their own engine for mobile, despite its popularity for mobile games.

Answer (score 0):

Partially, the problem with overheating can be solved by writing your own shaders (Built-in render pipeline). Completely solve this problem is possible only by changing the engine. If you don't want to burn your clients' devices, bypass Unity and Unreal. Both engines are the best in rendering empty scenes at extreme temperatures (on any platform). And no checkboxes, optimizations will help you.